Multicolumn index apparently not being used by MySQL
Here is my table:
CREATE TABLE `Score` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playerId` int NOT NULL,
  `points` int NOT NULL,
  `gameId` int NOT NULL,
  `isDeleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Score_playerId_fkey` (`playerId`),
  KEY `Score_gameId_fkey` (`gameId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Score_gameId_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`gameId`) REFERENCES `Game` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Score_playerId_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`playerId`) REFERENCES `Player` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=813 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

This is the query I'm trying to optimize:
SELECT *
FROM `Score`
WHERE `Score`.`gameId` = 2 AND `Score`.`isDeleted` = 0
ORDER BY `Score`.`points` DESC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;

Here is the output of EXPLAIN for this query:
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys       key                 key_len ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      Score   NULL        ref     Score_gameId_fkey   Score_gameId_fkey   4       const   160     100.00      Using where; Using filesort

What I understand from this (if I am interpreting this output correctly) is that there is a WHERE filter being applied on 160 rows.
In fact, there are exactly 160 rows in the table with gameId = 2:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Score WHERE gameId = 2;
COUNT(*)
160

I suppose that, after using the foreign key index on gameId, the resulting rows are being checked one by one for the value of the isDeleted field.
Therefore, I have tried adding these two indexes:
CREATE INDEX gameId_isDeleted ON `Score` (`gameId`, `isDeleted`);
CREATE INDEX isDeleted ON `Score` (`isDeleted`);

However, after those changes, the output for EXPLAIN still shows that only the is being used, because possible_keys says Score_gameId_fkey,gameId_isDeleted,isDeleted but key still says Score_gameId_fkey:
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys                                   key                 key_len ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      Score   NULL        ref     Score_gameId_fkey,gameId_isDeleted,isDeleted    Score_gameId_fkey   4       const   160     100.00      Using where; Using filesort

There is no difference if only the gameId_isDeleted or isDeleted index is present, or both (I tried all possible combinations by dropping and recreating them).
Am I interpreting the results of those two EXPLAIN statements correctly? If so, how can I best optimize the query?
Additionally, I understand that an index on the points field might also improve things by avoiding the filesort caused by the ORDER BY, is that correct?

AUTO_INCREMENT=813 I guess this is the maximum number of records present on the table , if so , in my opinion there are very few rows. Test the index on a couple of millions of rows

Having an index on gameid - points or gameid - isdeleted - points would be preferable to the ones you created. isdeleted column has very low selectivity (probably two possible values), so mysql tends to ignore such columns in indexes.

@Shadow the single column indexes were created by MySQL because gameId and playerId are foreign keys with references to other tables. I'm not sure if it would be a good idea to drop them, because of that reason.

FK can work with any keys where the referenced column is the leftmost one...

Sorting requires far more resources than filtering, so if you did add an index with points in it, that will probably be chosen as the key.

MySQL's cost-based optimizer is sometimes subtle and seems to have its own rules.

It estimates that it won't get much benefit from the compound index on gameId and isDeleted, because isDeleted=0 matches most (or all) of the rows anyway.
It therefore prefers the single-column index on gameId, because it's a "smaller" index. I.e. fewer columns, therefore more entries fit per page, therefore it's less costly to load the index into the buffer pool.

You could drop the single-column index on gameId. Any query that would use that index could also use the compound index in which gameId is the first column. This would simplify the optimizer's choice.
You could add points as a third column on this index. This would help to make the ORDER BY points a no-op, because the optimizer knows that the entries in the index are already sorted by points for given values of gameId, isDeleted. That is, for gameId=2 and isDeleted=0, the entries matching these two conditions are all tied, and if the third column of the index is points then these ties are by definition ordered by points. So the entries can simply be read in index order, and no sorting needs to be done. You should see "Using filesort" omitted from the EXPLAIN.
You might like my presentation How to Design Indexes, Really, or the video.
